# How to use the macro definition to modify the name of the function by passing parameters

Tags: c, function, macros, definition

My question is:
when i=1

```
P_COMInit(i) = do { P_SEGi_OUTMODE();}while(0)
```

but not

```
do{P_SEG1_OUTMODE();}while(0)
```

How can I achieve what I want?

I want to replace the code above with the macro definition

```
#define P_COMInit(n)
{\
    do{P_COM##n##_OUTMODE();\
    }while(0);\
}\
#define P_SEGInit(n)  do{P_SEG##n##_OUTMODE();}while(0)
 
#define MAX_COM_NUM  2
#define MAX_SEG_NUM    7
 
 
void main(void)
{
    /*  
    P_COM1_OUTMODE();
    P_COM2_OUTMODE();
    P_SEG1_OUTMODE();
    P_SEG2_OUTMODE();
    P_SEG3_OUTMODE(); 
    P_SEG4_OUTMODE();
    P_SEG5_OUTMODE(); 
    P_SEG6_OUTMODE();
    P_SEG7_OUTMODE();*/
    //I want to replace the code above with the below
    uchar i;
    for(i = 1;i <= MAX_COM_NUM;i++)
    {
        P_SEGInit(i);
    }
    for(i = 1;i <= MAX_SEG_NUM;i++)
    {
        P_COMInit(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The preprocessor is only executed in compile-time, never in run-time. So you can't pass variable values to it and rename functions based on run-time values. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I think there are too many repeated statements, I want to make the code more concise

Answer (score 1):

Originally it is no my macro (I am not an author - and author's name was forgotten by me, but sometimes I use it)

```
#define FE_0(WHAT)
#define FE_1(WHAT, X) WHAT(X) 
#define FE_2(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_1(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_3(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_2(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_4(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_3(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_5(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_4(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_6(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_5(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_7(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_6(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_8(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_7(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_9(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_8(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_10(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_9(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_11(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_10(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_12(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_11(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_13(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_13(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_14(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X)FE_13(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
//repeat more times if more arguments are needed

#define GET_MACRO(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,NAME,...) NAME
#define FOR_EACH(action,...) \
  GET_MACRO(_0,__VA_ARGS__,FE14,FE_13,FE_12,FE_11,FE_10,FE_9,FE_8,FE_7,FE_6,FE_5,FE_4,FE_3,FE_2,FE_1,FE_0)(action,__VA_ARGS__)


#define PCOM(X) P_COM ## X ## _OUTMODE();
#define PSEG(X) P_SEG ## X ## _OUTMODE();
#define CAT(NAME,...) FOR_EACH(NAME,__VA_ARGS__)

// Emit some code
CAT(PCOM,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7)
CAT(PSEG,1,2,3,4,3,4)
```

And it will emit:

```
P_COM1_OUTMODE();P_COM2_OUTMODE();P_COM3_OUTMODE();P_COM4_OUTMODE();P_COM3_OUTMODE();P_COM4_OUTMODE();P_COM5_OUTMODE();P_COM6_OUTMODE();P_COM7_OUTMODE();
P_SEG1_OUTMODE();P_SEG2_OUTMODE();P_SEG3_OUTMODE();P_SEG4_OUTMODE();P_SEG3_OUTMODE();P_SEG4_OUTMODE();
```

Comment: I don't think that's clearer than the original code — not that the original is all that clear with the macros hiding loops, etc.  But it does compress the code which seemed to be what the OP wanted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It compresses the source code (except .h file with macrodefinitions

Answer (score 0):

If you are going down the macro path (last resort) then at least stick to the somewhat standardized "X Macros". These collect all data at one single place in the program to minimize repetition. Easy to maintain, wickedly flexible, but hard to read.

In this case you'd create the X macro lists like this:

```
#define COM_LIST(X) \
  X(1)              \
  X(2)              \

#define SEG_LIST(X) \
  X(1)              \
  X(2)              \
  X(3)              \
  X(4)              \
  X(5)              \
  X(6)              \
  X(7)              \
```

You can create the macro constants `MAX_COM_NUM` etc by using these lists then create an enum to "count" the number of items.

```
typedef enum
{
  #define COM_ENUM(n) COM_ENUM_##n,
  COM_LIST(COM_ENUM)
  MAX_COM_NUM
} MAX_COM_t;

typedef enum
{
  #define SEG_ENUM(n) SEG_ENUM_##n,
  SEG_LIST(SEG_ENUM)
  MAX_SEG_NUM
} MAX_SEG_t;
```

Even if you aren't going to use these as enums, you now have a preprocessor item `MAX_COM_NUM` that equals 2 and one `MAX_SEG_NUM` which equals 7.

You can even use X-macros to generate the actual functions if you fancy (though I don't recommend it, maintaining/debugging code inside macros is no fun):

```
#define CREATE_COM_FUNC(n)       \
  void P_COM##n##_OUTMODE (void) \
  {                              \
    puts(__func__);              \
  }

COM_LIST(CREATE_COM_FUNC)
```

You can call and execute all functions like this:

```
#define CALL_ALL_PCOM_OUTMODE(n) P_COM##n##_OUTMODE();
COM_LIST(CALL_ALL_PCOM_OUTMODE)
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COM_LIST(X) \
  X(1)              \
  X(2)              \

#define SEG_LIST(X) \
  X(1)              \
  X(2)              \
  X(3)              \
  X(4)              \
  X(5)              \
  X(6)              \
  X(7)              \

// if all functions are of the same type we can get even more generic:
#define CREATE_FUNC(type, n)        \
  void P_##type##n##_OUTMODE (void) \
  {                                 \
    puts(__func__);                 \
  }

// wrapper macros to add the correct prefix:
#define CREATE_COM_FUNC(n) CREATE_FUNC(COM,n)
#define CREATE_SEG_FUNC(n) CREATE_FUNC(SEG,n)

// generate all function definitions:
COM_LIST(CREATE_COM_FUNC)
SEG_LIST(CREATE_SEG_FUNC)

int main(void)
{
  #define CALL_ALL_PCOM_OUTMODE(n) P_COM##n##_OUTMODE();
  COM_LIST(CALL_ALL_PCOM_OUTMODE)

  #define CALL_ALL_PSEG_OUTMODE(n) P_SEG##n##_OUTMODE();
  SEG_LIST(CALL_ALL_PSEG_OUTMODE)
}
```

Output:

```
P_COM1_OUTMODE
P_COM2_OUTMODE
P_SEG1_OUTMODE
P_SEG2_OUTMODE
P_SEG3_OUTMODE
P_SEG4_OUTMODE
P_SEG5_OUTMODE
P_SEG6_OUTMODE
P_SEG7_OUTMODE
```